# Intune Device configuration, "OneDrive Files On-Demand" Not applicable

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, onedrive, intune, configuration-profile

I have created a configuration profile on intune :

[image]

In "AVD - IT" group there is only one device, a virtual machine (created with Azure virtual desktop) with this os :

Edition Windows 11 Enterprise multi-session
Version 22H2
Installed on    ‎8/‎3/‎2023
OS build    22621.2134

The VM is well connected to Azure AD.
The problem is that the status of this policy is "not applicable":
[image]

Any idea why? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a closer look at the documentation here : [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/fundamentals/azure-virtual-desktop-multi-session) :
[image]

So I create a new configuration profile from scratch (ie settings catalog) instead of using templates and it worked.
[image]